# Create a MySQL Database using a MS SQL database dump (.CSV)

Tags: mysql, restore, csv

I have a dump of a MS SQL database in the form of CSV files for every table in the database. There are 679 .csv files each for every table. The highest size of the table extract is 9 GB and the lowest is 12 bytes.

I want to replicate the entire database on MySQL keeping all the table structure and relationships intact. The purpose is to replicate the database on MySQL so I can query the results when required.

How can I do that please?

Many Thanks,
Jitendra

Comment: Sorry to be that guy but have you even researched importing CSV into MySQL, or did you get this task and come directly to SE without any prior research?

Comment: Are you going on to Unix/Linux? Does MS SQL Server not have the possibility of dumping to DDL and DML? If you have those, then using sed, awk and grep in Unix mightn't require **too** much work. It'll be a big job though - making sure that the data is identical, no truncation has occurred &c. What is your programming expertise?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... you say that you have a .csv dump of the tables of a database? What version of SQL Server was this database extracted from? 679 tables is a largish system and this will require a **lot** of work.

Where are the inter-table relationships stored? You can't store `FOREIGN KEY` relationships in a .csv dump. Neither can you store `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s which MySQL doesn't support anyway (although this can be done programmatically [through triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584093/conversion-from-microsoft-sql-server-to-mysql) - but can be tricky and error-prone). `

**More** importantly, a .csv won't tell you what the datatype is - it might give a clue, but a column with a run of `INTEGER`s could actually require a `FLOAT`/`REAL` type. Also, how do you know the real length of a `VARCHAR` field? Just because all of yours are < 30 `CHAR`s, who's to say that a greater length won't be required?

This is to say nothing of `TRIGGER`s and `STORED PROCEDURE`s which are a completely different kettle of fish and could (depending on your database complexity) require months. In the area of these, MySQL is very much a lightweight in terms of its capabilities in this area.

MS SQL Server is a **much** more powerful RDBMS than MySQL - having the data is only a first step - but there'll be way more to do than just "simply" loading tables.

Your 1st step should be to get hold of the DDL and DML of this database, because without it, your task is going to be virtually impossible. 
You should take a look at [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/migrate-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql) - it gives you three different methods of converting (a running) Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL.

It appears to particularly recommend MySQL Workbench - which I also recommend as an excellent GUI tool for such work. This depends on having ongoing access to a running server. You'll also need an ODBC connection to the SQL Server.

A question here gives you two options to [extract DML and DDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929815/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-a-full-database-ddl-for-sql-server-what-about-postg) from a SQL Server database to build a script (that won't work **immediately** on MySQL) - but with this, at least you have a fighting chance. You may also find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584093/conversion-from-microsoft-sql-server-to-mysql) helpful.

Even then, you'll have a **lot** of testing to do - you're going to need Unix (or Windows Powershell) scripting or some programming (ideally Python or Perl) skills.

After you have basic table scripts - don't expect many of them to work first time - determine all tables which don't have any `FOREIGN KEY`s - usually lookup/reference tables (countries, cities, codes &c.) and make sure they load successfully. Then find the tables that have more and more `FOREIGN KEY`s and gradually build a cohesive system.

I would suggest a staging approach - you'll have to go back and check that your data in the MySQL database corresponds exactly to the data in your SQL Server database.

Another suggestion that I would have is to do a smaller project first to get a realistic idea of your timeframe. You could start here [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584093/conversion-from-microsoft-sql-server-to-mysql).

You need to get a **serious** project plan in place and if you're doing this on your own, you need to plan for a serious amount of time - if you're not really a database person, you need to bring somebody on board. Best of luck with your project!